# Java Swing - Dynamically change JList using TransferHandler

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jlist

I have a small Java swingui app where I display a JList and the user is able to cut, copy, paste and sort the list.

I use a custom TransferHandler to allow drag and drop on this Jlist. Here is the code in building the JList, it basically builds it from an ArrayList. "lstScripts" is the JList.

```
    ListTransferHandler lh = new ListTransferHandler();
...
    DefaultListModel listModelScripts = new DefaultListModel();
    for(Script s : scripts) {
        listModelScripts.addElement(s.getName());
    }
    this.lstScripts = new JList(listModelScripts);
    this.lstScripts.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    this.lstScripts.addListSelectionListener(this);
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(this.lstScripts);
    sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
    this.lstScripts.setDragEnabled(true);
    this.lstScripts.setTransferHandler(lh);
    this.lstScripts.setDropMode(DropMode.ON_OR_INSERT);
    setMappings(this.lstScripts);
...
```

On my custom TransferHandler class, I've got the importData routine working so that it handles the copy/paste/cut/sort.

```
public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {
    String scriptname = null; // The script name on the list

    //If we can't handle the import, bail now.
    if (!canImport(info)) {
        return false;
    }

    JList list = (JList)info.getComponent();
    DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)list.getModel();
    //Fetch the scriptname -- bail if this fails
    try {
        scriptname = (String)info.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ufe) {
        System.out.println("importData: unsupported data flavor");
        return false;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("importData: I/O exception");
        return false;
    }

    if (info.isDrop()) { //This is a drop
        JList.DropLocation dl = (JList.DropLocation)info.getDropLocation();
        int index = dl.getIndex();
        model.add(index, scriptname);
        return true;
    } else { //This is a paste
        int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
        // if there is a valid selection,
        // insert scriptname after the selection
        if (index >= 0) {
            model.add(list.getSelectedIndex()+1, scriptname);
        // else append to the end of the list
        } else {
            model.addElement(scriptname);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

So up to here, everything works fine as far as the GUI. But my problem is I need the original JList "lstScripts" to be automatically updated with the user GUI changes. For example, if the user cuts or reorders the list, I want it to show on in "lstScripts".

I'm not seeing how to make this connection between the TransferHandler and original GUI controller where "lstScripts" resides.

Comment: You have access to the `ListModel`?  If you really have to you, could also pass a controller to the `ListTransferHandler`...

Comment: unrelated: [don't use setXXSize, ever](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229519/203657)

Comment: I don't understand the question: you are modifying the model, so updates simply happens - or do you have two lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kleopatra - you helped me! sorry I didnt understand how the model was working.

So in the controller, I create the "lstScripts" JList and add it to my panel (this is the first block of my code above).

```
 pnlScripts.add(lstScripts, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

And as my code above showed, the listScripts JList had a custom transferhandler set as such:

```
 this.lstScripts.setTransferHandler(lh);
```

So the transferhandler does all the user dnd (drag and drop) stuff. In the controller, I can get the updated list by doing:

```
 DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)lstScripts.getModel();
 for (int i = 0; i < model.getSize(); i++){
     scriptnames += model.getElementAt(i).toString() + ",";
 }
```

The scriptnames String variable now contains the updated list.

Thanks!